# Getting a ref/address from a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, collections, reference

I am aware that C# does not deal with pointers but I wonder if I can get a ref to a list when I know its first element?
For example:
Let's say I have a list defined as

```
List<T> abc
```

If I have abc[0], can I get a reference of abc?
I am new to C#, I apologize if my question seems weird. In C/C++, I can get the address of an array abc by using &abc[0]. Does C# provide us with similar tool that help us refer back to the collection itself when we know one item in the collection?
Thanks,

Comment: I think the big question as an answer to your question is: what is it that you try to do? It IS possible to work with pointers in C#, but in general there's absolutely no need to, could you elaborate a little more about what it is that you want to achieve?

Comment: I do agree that while doing what you asked is probably possible, I suspect that there is a larger goal you are trying to accomplish--something that might be easier by looking at the problem in a different way.

Comment: Thanks Arthur for looking into my question. Basically, I have a whole bunch of List<T> let call them abc, def, ghi, jlk.... I have a generic method that is going to trigger another method that will  process all the elements inside one of the available lists depending on which list the element I receive belong to.

Comment: @user1205746 Then you should just pass the list that should be processed directly, rather than just passing one item in that list.  You could also pass a single item as well if you need it for some other reason.

Comment: for this use-case i would define my own list (make it a wrapper over the framework one) and on Add i would subscribe to an event exposed by the added item and fire an event of my own that an external listener will handle. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Actually, c# *does* deal with pointers; what you ask is entirely possible if using an *array* rather than a list. You require the "unsafe" keyword, though.

Comment: @MarcGravell - but he'll have to work only with value types to get the pointerToArray == ponterToFirstElement assumption

Comment: @AZ. Yes, it has limitations.

Comment: @Servy: It would be nice if I could change the protocol. If there is no other alternative, then I have to suggest the protocol be changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Collections don't work the same way in C# as they do in C++, for example you can add the same object to multiple different collections and so it doesn't really make sense to ask to get a reference to the list that an object is contained in, as it could be in many lists (or none, or even in the same list multiple times)

```
object myObject = new object();

List<object> list = new List<object>();
list.Add(myObject);

object[] someArray = new object[] { myObject  };
Assert.AreEqual(list[0], someArray[0]);
```

If it helps you can think of lists in C# as being lists of <strike>pointers</strike> references to the objects being stored where the pointer itself is hidden from you, although understand that in reality the implementation may be more complicated (and is also irrelevant).

If there is a relationship between the objects in a list and the list contents of that list then its up to you to explicitly declare and keep track of what that realtionsip is, for example through a `Parent` property on the object in the list

```
List<T> myList = new List<T>();

// Whenever an item is added to myList set the Parent property
myList.Add(item);
item.Parent = myList;
```

This is what Windows Forms does in order to maintain the relationship between the controls in a container, and the container in which those controls are contained.  Obviously you should decide what to do if someone tries to add the same object to multiple lists.

Comment: i would argue that collections in .NET work the same way as the C++ ones (where List<T> = std:vector<*T> and LinkedList<T> = std:list<*T>). The only difference is that for reference types you can only have lists of pointers and the std:vector<T> behavior will only work for value types. Nice answer +1.

Comment: @Justin: Thanks! so if I understand you correctly, the property Parent is there in object for us to use?

Comment: no it is not. You have to declare a type with a Parent property on it.

Comment: As @AdrianZanescu already pointed out, the key to understanding here is the difference between  [value types and reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/types). Reference types are in a variable, and equally in the collection, represented by reference (i. e. pointer hidden from you), while value types are directly in the place.  

In C++, you can finely control this behavior. In C# you can not. You simply have to decide to use either class (reference type, references all the time) or struct (value type, values all the time).

Answer (score 12):

This is now possible, starting with .NET 5.0, by using the [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.asspan) method.

As indicated by the documentation, items should not be added to or removed from the list while using the span or item references taken from the span. Technically this should also be extended to say that the `Capacity` should not be changed nor should `TrimExcess()` be called. If these operations are used while actively using the span or its references, then the internal memory of the list may no longer be the same as the memory in the span.

```
// Create a simple list with three items.
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(123);
list.Add(456);
list.Add(789);

// Print list to console.
Console.WriteLine("List items:");
foreach (var item in list)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
Console.WriteLine();

// Get a reference to the second item in the list.
// WARNING: DO NOT ADD/REMOVE ITEMS FROM THE LIST WHILE USING THIS SPAN
// OR ANY REFERENCES DERIVED FROM THIS SPAN!
var listSpan = CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(list);
ref var secondItem = ref listSpan[1];
Console.WriteLine($"Referenced value (original): {secondItem}");

// Change the referenced list item.
secondItem = 0;
Console.WriteLine($"Referenced value (modified): {secondItem}");
Console.WriteLine();

// Print the list to console.
Console.WriteLine("List items:");
foreach (var item in list)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
Console.WriteLine();
```

You should get output like this:

```
List items:
123
456
789

Referenced value (original): 456
Referenced value (modified): 0

List items:
123
0
789
```

Comment: This needs to be part of the accepted answer, it's hidden under the older one, which could mislead people.

Answer (score 2):

If you are designing the type of the items in the collection, then you can add a property to the item's type that "points" to the containing list; when you construct each item, pass in the containing list and save this in the property.

Something like this:

```
class ListItem
{
    public List<ListItem> Parent { get; set; }

    public ListItem(List<ListItem> parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }
}

ListItem listItem = new ListItem(abc);
abc.Add(listItem);

// Get collection from item.
List<T> def = listItem.Parent;
```

Comment: Pay attention to memory leaks!

Comment: @AS-CII Managed code can "leak" memory (i.e. inadvertantly use memory that the developer intended to be released, that actually isn't), however this code probably wouldn't fall under that category.

Comment: Thanks, ShellShock. How do I "point" to the containing list? That's the issue I am struggling with.

Comment: @user1205746 You are always "pointing" to the list in c# as it a reference type.

Comment: @Rotem: Could you please elaborate on your statement "you are always pointing to the list"? I only have an element in the collection. How can I refer to the collection and not the item?

Comment: @user1205746 What I meant is that following @Shellshock 's proposed implementation, the new property on your `Item` which references the *parent* of the item, is a reference which "points" to the list, and not a new instance of `List`. Elaborated in Justin's answer

Comment: @Rotem The GC isn't that naive of an implementation.  It doesn't keep anything alive if it is ever pointed to.  It is designed such that if there are circular references (which is what this is) and none of the objects in the circle are referenced (directly or indirectly) by any root nodes (which is any static variable or anything on the stack) then they will be collected.  Here, if there are no stack variables referencing either an item or the list, the whole thing will be GCed just fine.

Comment: @Servy Where did I claim otherwise?

Comment: @Rotem Sorry, the topic switch halfway through the comment thread and I mistakenly though your comment was in reference to the previous topic.  Feel free to ignore me.

Answer (score 2):

Not unless the type of abc[0] explicitly holds a reference to the list. In fact you cannot do that in C++ either without an explicit reference.

Think about it, in C++ if you can expect `firstElemPtr == arrayPtr` it is just because arrays store the elements that way and it only works for arrays; everything else is just by accident.

Now consider any list structure that allocates something else (maybe element count) before the pointer to the first element. Your assumption will not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
unsafe static void Main() {
    int[] arr = new int[100];
    fixed(int* ptr = arr) {
        // ptr is a pointer to the zeroth item in the array

    }
}
```

However, unsafe code is not all that common in c# and should be limited to performance-critical regions (and even then used sparingly). In particular, note that we have "pinned" the array by doing this - and note that `ptr` is only reliable *while* it is pinned. Outside of the `fixed` block, GC is free to relocate the array, making `ptr` invalid.

Clarification: I don't suggest you should do this, but: such things are entirely possible.

Comment: it does not exactly match the OP situation. He has access to an item reference and wants to obtain the container array. i suppose it will be a ref type because if a value type he might have a copy altogether (unless we consider ref passing etc.). From that no matter what he uses he won't be able to obtain the pointer/reference of the holding array.

Comment: @AZ Especially as there can be more than one holding array.

Answer (score 0):

List is defined somewhat like this:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T> blabla
{
    private T [] data;

    public T this[int index] { 
        get { return data[index]; } 
        set { data[index]=value; }
    }
    ... blabla
}
```

YES, it is NOT linked list of any kind. So you must use it accordingly. Though since .NET value types are small and class types are all references, there usually no heavy array-copy operations as it is possible with C++ for example so such implementation of general-puprose collection is good enough (unless abused). Vector could be a better name from academic standpoint, but it's not.

You would not be able to get a reference to data array, as it's private variable. Nor you would have any need for this. If you need enumerator, use GetEnumerator explicitely or foreach for implicit use.